# Home page navigation shows up first sub category but rest of the pages show all sub categories

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Using Magento 1.9.2.3, I am developing a Magento website. I have set up everything. Now, I set up categories as you can see in the pictures below. I have one problem with the home page.

- The main home page shows only the first categories subs.
- The other pages show all the categories with no problems.

Any help is appreciated. I have uploaded screens of outputs that you can go through

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you refreshed cache and indexes judging from your tabs, so the only thing I can think it would be is an error in the theme when generating the nav. I would first search and see if the home page header is generated separately from all other pages (which is very well possible due to the slider), and then check to see if there are any differences in the nav generation.

Answer (score 0):

Does your homepage use another template as the other pages? 
If so, check difference of the generation of the menu in both templates.